# JSON.parse returns children objects with null value, children values not being parsed

Tags: javascript, json

I have a JavaScript object that I am stringifying with JSON.stringify that returns a JSON string with parent and children data.

When I try to parse this string back to an object, the children objects are now null.

```
function cacheForm(agency) {

 var agency = ko.toJS(this); //easy way to get a clean copy
 delete agency.contacts; //remove an extra property

        for (i in agency.offices) {
            for (val in agency.offices[i]) {
                //delete agency.offices[i].agency;
                //delete agency.offices[i].agencyID;
            }
        }

            for (i in agency.offices) {
                for (ii in agency.offices[i].contacts) {
                    for (val in agency.offices[i].contacts[ii]) {
                        //delete agency.offices[i].contacts[ii].office;
                        //delete agency.offices[i].contacts[ii].agencyID;
                        //delete agency.offices[i].contacts[ii].officeID;
                    }
                }
            }

                 var value = agency;

                 var cache = [];
                 parsed = JSON.stringify(value, function (key, value) {
                     if (typeof value === 'object' && value !== null) {
                         if (cache.indexOf(value) !== -1) {
                             // Circular reference found, discard key
                             return;
                         }
                         // Store value in our collection
                         cache.push(value); 
                     }

                     return value;
                 });


                 var data = JSON.parse(parsed);
    }
```

**Edit**

Agency part of my view model that I am passing into my cacheForm function and I am using

```
 var agency = ko.toJS(this);
```

to have my data available in an object which can be parsed to JSON string. I may of deleted this code in my post because my original code had many annotations.

[image: My agency object before stringify - it has child data]

Comment: Seeing actual JSON will help us, can u post link to it if possible?

Comment: use http://fpaste.org or use paste bin to paste your json

Comment: Yeah, give us actual data. Anyway, my bet is on "Note: You cannot use the replacer function to remove values from an array. If you return undefined or a function then null is used instead." ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_native_JSON#The_replacer_parameter))

Comment: http://fpaste.org/33076/37691240/ Password is test

Comment: In the json that you have provided at the link, offices is already an array with one element which is null. Can we see the original JSON of actual object.

Comment: I have added a picture of my object before stringify to show it has child data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I eventually solved my problem and this is how I did it.

```
function cacheForm(agency) {
    // GET my object from agency vm
    var agency = ko.toJS(agency);

    var s = YUI().use("json-stringify", function (Y) {    
        var jsonStrAgency = Y.JSON.stringify(agency, ["activities", "agencyName", "agencyID", "campaignBillings", "category", "declaredBillings", "immediateParent", "numberOfEmployees", "ultimateParent", "uRL"]); // Use an array of acceptable object key names as a whitelist.
        var jsonStrOffices, jsonStrContacts;

        for (i in agency.offices) {
            jsonStrOffices = Y.JSON.stringify(agency.offices, ["address1", "address2", "address3", "address4", "address5", "agencyID", "faxNumber", "officeID", "postCode", "telephoneNumber"]);

        for (ii in agency.offices[i].contacts) {
                    jsonStrContacts = Y.JSON.stringify(agency.offices[i].contacts, ["agencyID", "emailAddress", "firstName", "jobName", "officeID", "personID", "surName", "title"]);
            }
        }

        localStorage.setItem('Agency', jsonStrAgency);
        localStorage.setItem('Offices', jsonStrOffices);
        localStorage.setItem('Contacts', jsonStrContacts);
    });
}
```

Firstly I am passing in my ko.observableArray to the function cacheForm. This parameter is called agency and it is part of my viewmodel.

I want to parse my observableArray and convert it into a standard javascript object. By using ko.toJS I can do this. There will be no ko constructors after using toJS.

Then I have to get my JSON strings. Since my object has children and grandchildren I have to parse these parts separately. Stringify doesn't like arrays within an object, they will be changed to null and your children data will be lost.

Because of circular recursion, I have to use this:

```
 var s = YUI().use("json-stringify", function (Y) {
```

This is part of the Yahoo API. This is the script reference:

```
<script src="http://yui.yahooapis.com/3.11.0/build/yui/yui-min.js"></script>
```

Y.JSON.stringify takes an object as one parameter and an option paremter which is an array. The purpose of this array is to contain the property names of the object you want to stringify. From other forums I found out this is known as whitelisting.

With all my JSON strings I can store them in HTML5 local storage.

When the page loads I then check to see if my local storage contains data. If true I retrieve my data and serialize from JSON string to a javascript object.

```
define(['services/datacontext'], function (dataContext) {
    var initialized = false;
    var agency;

    if (localStorage.Agency && localStorage.Offices && localStorage.Contacts) {
        var objAgency = new Object(ko.mapping.fromJSON(localStorage.getItem('Agency')));
        var objOffices = new Object(ko.mapping.fromJSON(localStorage.getItem('Offices')));
        var objContacts = new Object(ko.mapping.fromJSON(localStorage.getItem('Contacts')));

        objAgency.offices = objOffices;
        objAgency.offices._latestValue[0].contacts = objContacts;


        agency = ko.observableArray([ko.mapping.fromJS(objAgency)]);
        ko.applyBindings(agency);

        initialized = true;

    }
    else {
        agency = ko.observableArray([]);
    }
```

Finally I reconstruct my object to how it was before stringify and map it back to an observableArray and finally bind it.

Hopefully this helps other people using a combination of knockoutJS and complicated objects.

See below for my full code:

```
define(['services/datacontext'], function (dataContext) {
    var initialized = false;
    var agency;

    if (localStorage.Agency && localStorage.Offices && localStorage.Contacts) {
        var objAgency = new Object(ko.mapping.fromJSON(localStorage.getItem('Agency')));
        var objOffices = new Object(ko.mapping.fromJSON(localStorage.getItem('Offices')));
        var objContacts = new Object(ko.mapping.fromJSON(localStorage.getItem('Contacts')));

        objAgency.offices = objOffices;
        objAgency.offices._latestValue[0].contacts = objContacts;


        agency = ko.observableArray([ko.mapping.fromJS(objAgency)]);
        ko.applyBindings(agency);

        initialized = true;

    }
    else {
        agency = ko.observableArray([]);
    }


    var save = function (agency, myStoredValue) {
        // Clear Cache because user submitted the form. We don't have to hold onto data anymore.
        //amplify.store("Agency", null);
        return dataContext.saveChanges(agency);
    };

    var vm = { // This is my view model, my functions are bound to it. 
        //These are wired up to my agency view
        activate: activate,
        agency: agency,
        title: 'agency',
        refresh: refresh, // call refresh function which calls get Agencies
        save: save,
        cacheForm: cacheForm
    };
    return vm;

    function activate() {

        vm.agency;

        if (initialized) {
            return;
        }

        initialized = false;

        return refresh();

    }

    function refresh() {
        return dataContext.getAgency(agency);
    }


    function cacheForm(agency) {
        // GET my object from agency vm
        var agency = ko.toJS(agency);

        var s = YUI().use("json-stringify", function (Y) {

            var jsonStrAgency = Y.JSON.stringify(agency, ["activities", "agencyName", "agencyID", "campaignBillings", "category", "declaredBillings", "immediateParent", "numberOfEmployees", "ultimateParent", "uRL"]); // Use an array of acceptable object key names as a whitelist.
            var jsonStrOffices, jsonStrContacts;

            for (i in agency.offices) {
                jsonStrOffices = Y.JSON.stringify(agency.offices, ["address1", "address2", "address3", "address4", "address5", "agencyID", "faxNumber", "officeID", "postCode", "telephoneNumber"]);

                for (ii in agency.offices[i].contacts) {
                    jsonStrContacts = Y.JSON.stringify(agency.offices[i].contacts, ["agencyID", "emailAddress", "firstName", "jobName", "officeID", "personID", "surName", "title"]);
                }
            }

            localStorage.setItem('Agency', jsonStrAgency);
            localStorage.setItem('Offices', jsonStrOffices);
            localStorage.setItem('Contacts', jsonStrContacts);
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Your question initially showed a screen shot where `data.offices = [null]` was highlighted.

It's not a parsing error, but an error in `stringify`. Your paste already has `data.offices = [null]`.

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_native_JSON#The_replacer_parameter) states regarding `replacer`:

> Note: You cannot use the replacer function to remove values from an array. If you return undefined or a function then null is used instead.

And furthermore regarding [`stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify):

> If undefined, a function, or an XML value is encountered during conversion it is either omitted (when it is found in an object) or censored to null (when it is found in an array).

I don't have access to your original object, and hence cannot tell which of the two you are hitting...

Implementing [`toJSON`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#toJSON_behavior) (or just explicitly constructing another object from the source object) instead of a `replacer` to filter arrays would be the way to go, if the problem is within your current `replacer` implementation.

Comment: I am not sure what I would supply to stringify for it to filter arrays. Do you have an example?

Comment: The documentation states: You cannot supply anything to `stringify` to filter arrays. You can construct an already filtered object and supply that to `stringify`, either implicitly by implementing `toJSON` on your object, or explicitly like `JSON.stringify(doFilterMyObject(obj))`.

Answer (score 1):

there are various js libraries predefined for parsing json and to get children values . What i usually do to parse json  is use http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/json/ YUI library.